# Can I customize Google Map to like this?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My client wanted me to update his Google map to a 'new' one, which looks like this: http://snag.gy/McZSd.jpg. Is there any setting used?

Comment: if you could specify what your client means by 'new' more people might chime in

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to look at is [Google Map's map types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your client's Google map is a JS map, the first step is to turn on visual refresh to get the new colors and fonts: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-refresh

As to building new style UI controls over a full bleed map, that is going to require you to spend some time in HTML and CSS land. =)